# Elasticsearch delete/update a document in index1 and index2

Tags: search, elasticsearch

If I have two index, Ex: sample1 and sample2. 
If I delete or update a value in sample1 then the corresponding document should also deleted or updated in sample2?

Data : sample1 : {name: 'Tom', id: '1', city: 'xx', state, 'yy', country: 'zz'}
       sample2 : {id: '1', city: 'xx', state, 'yy', country: 'zz'}
If I delete id: '1' then this document should be deleted from both the index from the server side itself. How to do this ? 
The problem will be if I delete the values separatley then if I end up in network issue after deleting value from one index the other index will have values how to avoid this ?

Comment: This sounds like a relational DB operation that you want to mirror in Elasticsearch... If it's like that and you use `id: 1` as a pseudo primary key, then you have some conceptual wrong thinking about Elasticsearch. It is not a relational DB in the classic rel. DB meaning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [bulk API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html) for doing this and you'll have better guarantees that both delete/update operations succeed or fail since everything happens in a single network call:

For deleting both documents in two different indices:

```
POST _bulk
{"delete": {"_index": "index1", "_type": "type1", "_id": "1"}}
{"delete": {"_index": "index2", "_type": "type2", "_id": "1"}}
```

For updating both documents in two different indices:

```
POST _bulk
{"index": {"_index": "index1", "_type": "type1", "_id": "1"}}
{"name": "Tom", id: "1", "city": "xx", "state": "yy", "country": "zz"}
{"index": {"_index": "index2", "_type": "type2", "_id": "1"}}
{"id": "1", "city": "xx", "state": "yy", "country": "zz"}
```

**UPDATE**

After discussing this, it seemed the needed solution was a mix of using

- the [delete-by-query API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-delete-by-query.html) (don't forget to [install the plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/2.4/plugins-delete-by-query.html) if you're on ES 2.x) for deleting documents matching a country in multiple indices
- and the [update-by-query API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/docs-update-by-query.html) for updating documents in multiple indices.

Comment: When I run bulk API update is not working. I am getting this error ."type": "action_request_validation_exception",
    "reason": "Validation Failed: 1: no requests added;"

Comment: You need to make sure that you have a new line after the last line too

Comment: I need to query by country field while deleting documents in bulk. country field matching documents should be deleted in both the index. How to do this ?

Comment: In that case, the delete-by-query solution by @Kulansagar would probably be better

Comment: how to pass the delete by query in sense plugin. I have tried this first and it's not working.

Comment: There is no support for delete by query elastic search 2.x versions. is there any alternate options.

Comment: Of course there is, you need to install a plugin: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/2.4/plugins-delete-by-query.html

Comment: Use the update by query API: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/docs-update-by-query.html

Comment: "script": {    "inline": "ctx._source.likes++" } . I am not clear on this. What the above statement does ? What should i do if i need to update country field in both indexes ?

Comment: `"script": { "inline": "ctx._source.country = 'new_country'" }`

Comment: {  "query": {  "term": {  "name": "Hai"  } },
   "script": { "inline": "ctx._source.name = 'sss'" }} I am trying to run this query executed successfully but its not updating the name to 'sss'

Comment: Getting this response for the above query {
   "took": 10,
   "timed_out": false,
   "total": 0,
   "updated": 0,
   "batches": 0,
   "version_conflicts": 0,
   "noops": 0,
   "retries": 0,
   "throttled_millis": 0,
   "requests_per_second": "unlimited",
   "throttled_until_millis": 0,
   "failures": []
}

Comment: your query is probably not matching anything. Do you get any documents if you only run the query part?

Comment: Thank You so much for your help. It's working the problem is with the query.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127469/discussion-between-user3351014-and-val).

Answer (score 1):

There is no clean way to do this with elasticsearch. What you want/need feels like a transaction and that is not possible with elastic. What you could do is do a bulk request with the 2 queries to update/delete the item in there. Still you have to check the response of the bulk to see if both queries went well. The chances for one of them failing might be a little bit smaller.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do both at the same time, I mean deleting the same document in two different indexes.

But then deleting a document from an index could be done using the `Delete By Query API` by giving a matchin query so that the appropriate document could be deleted.

Source: [Delete By Query API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-delete-by-query.html)

Comment: i have edited my question could yoy please suggest on that

Comment: delete by query is removed from version 2.0 . Please suggest any other options available for the latest version ?

Comment: I have tried this and not working for two index. DELETE twitter,new
{
   "field1"  : "tes-1"  
}

Answer (score 0):

Elasticsearch cannot guarantee you that it will do those two operations atomically, like a transaction in RDBs. I suggest looking at [nested documents](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/2.x/nested-objects.html) or [parent/child relationships](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/2.x/parent-child.html) for what Elasticsearch understands by joined documents.

In this way, if you deleted the parent, the children will be deleted as well.