# Elasticsearch while updating one index it should also update other index values

Tags: search, elasticsearch, lucene

I need to update a lat_long field in 'ADDRESS' index when updating the values in the 'USER' index. Is there a way to trigger event in elasticsearch internally from the server side to update the Address index while updating the USERindex ?

Comment: There is no automatic way to do it (i.e. no triggers) but this answer should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40415920/elasticsearch-delete-update-a-document-in-index1-and-index2/40416827#40416827

Comment: @Val. Is it possbile in elasticsearch to specify certain queries should go only to a specific nodes ?

Comment: You might want to explain a bit more about your use case in order for people to understand what you'd like to achieve?

Comment: @Val please have a look at this link and provide your suggestions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40481580/elasticsearch-balance-load-between-the-server-independently