# Elasticsearch balance load between the server independently

Tags: search, elasticsearch

If I have "4" nodes and from 4 nodes 2 nodes is for online and 2 nodes is for batch processing.

Online will retrieve requests from end user through UI and 
batch processing will send requests in file format.

When the traffic is high in the online server this traffic should not go to the batch nodes.

Both the servers should act independently and process the request.

How to balance the load without hitting the batch servers ?

Comment: If the "online" nodes and the "batch" nodes have nothing in common and should be completely separate, why not simply creating two different clusters? Another way is to use [shard allocation filtering](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/shard-allocation-filtering.html) in order to locate indices for "online" use on the two "online" nodes and indices for "batch" processing on the two "batch" nodes.

Comment: @Val we have same data index for both the online and batch requests only the query request is different.

Comment: You should probably better illustrate one or two of your use cases and your expectations.

Comment: @Val Online request comes from the end user and the batch request is a file request and also the response will be in file format. Expectation is online query should go to a specific node and batch query request should go to specific node. All the 4 nodes have same document but the query request should go for different nodes for online and batch.